# SQL Server INNER JOIN makes problems?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to join 5 tables using Inner Join.

Is this a good practice or will it make any inconsistency in later years?

Just have a look

```
SELECT Distinct(email)
FROM AP_GROUPS_INTO_ORGANIZATION M 
INNER JOIN GROUPSDB G on G.ID = M.GROUPID
INNER JOIN aspnet_Roles r ON R.RoleName = G.GROUPNAME
INNER JOIN aspnet_UsersInRoles U ON U.RoleId = R.RoleId  
INNER JOIN aspnet_membership a on a.UserId = U.UserId
WHERE G.GROUPNAME = 'GROUP001'
```

Comment: 5 `JOIN`s is OK if that's what you need semantically. I'd probably change to `WHERE EXISTS` rather than `JOIN` then get rid of duplicates with `DISTINCT` though. Make sure you look at the query plan and add any required indexes on the FK columns.

Comment: @Martin I would be wary of recommending the use of DISTINCT so freely. I have seen situations where developers write a query, see a bunch of duplicates and just stick in DISTINCT to get rid of them without understanding what is happening.  Im not saying thats the case here but its just not something I would encourage people to use without some consideration.

Comment: @Kaius - I definitely did not recommend `DISTINCT` I said the opposite to that in fact and that they should use `WHERE EXISTS` **instead** (though perhaps not strongly enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fine. I see you are using the aspnet tables in the query and i would advise against altering their structure or indexes without some testing first to ensure you dont create new problems.

Its pretty common to have this number of joins if your data is highly normalized.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I would change, and its from the basis of putting the table basing your criteria restrictions up front instead of lower in the joined tables would be to move your groups table up front like...  Additionally, the indentation helps to clearly show the relationships between tables.

```
SELECT
      Distinct(email)
   FROM
      GROUPSDB G
         INNER JOIN AP_GROUPS_INTO_ORGANIZATION M 
            ON G.ID = M.GROUPID
         INNER JOIN aspnet_Roles r
            ON G.GROUPNAME = R.RoleName
            INNER JOIN aspnet_UsersInRoles U 
               ON R.RoleId = U.RoleId
               INNER JOIN aspnet_membership a 
                  on U.UserId = a.UserId
   WHERE
      G.GROUPNAME = 'GROUP001'
```